# Better way to get best-fit regression formula (forcing y-int = 0)

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm looking at a data set and trying to understand relationships between what is charged and what is paid.

First pass with a simple regression using excel's data analysis regression tool gives the following, without forcing zero intercept:

[image: Residuals Plot]

Second pass with forcing zero intercept:

[image: Residuals Plot]

I get better R squared values (0.82 vs 0.35) by forcing the zero intercept, but it looks like it is only because the residuals balance out.  Is there a better way to run a regression here to get a best fit formula?

Comment: The formula for $R^2$ is different when you have no intercept. You *cannot* compare them.